# Keep line breaks in javascript ( alpine )

Tags: javascript, laravel, alpine.js

I am working with a functionality that cuts a paragraph if it has more than 200 characters and adds a **...read** more button and when the button is clicked the whole text is shown.

The problem is that the text is displayed without line breaks and from the database is formatted, even the variable is passed from PHP with **nl2br**.

the code

```
<p
    x-data="{ isCollapsed: false, maxLength: 200, originalContent: '', content: '' }"
    x-init="originalContent = $el.firstElementChild.textContent.trim(); content = originalContent.slice(0, maxLength)"
    >
        <span x-text="isCollapsed ? originalContent : content">{!! nl2br(e($content->socialCreate->text)) !!}</span>
        <button
            class="font-extrabold"
            @click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed"
            x-show="originalContent.length > maxLength"
            x-text="isCollapsed ? 'Esconder' : '...Leer mas'"
        ></button>
</p>
```

How can I make the text display with line breaks?

Answer (score 1):

I think the database may turn your line breaks `<br>` into `\n`. It it isn't rendering the `\n`, so you'll probably need to a `.replace("\n","<br>")`.

Comment: Sorry, now it replaces correctly and adds the <br> tag but not the line break.

Comment: Hmm, you might have to share your CSS code. I've never used any of your frameworks, I was just guessing, since the same thing happened to me.